# What is this trapezoid-shaped logic component?

Tags: computer-architecture, arithmetic, memory-hardware

This is from http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~milom/cse240-Fall05/handouts/Ch05.pdf , slide 9.

[image]

From this diagram, I recognize 0001 as the opcode, which corresponds to the ADD instruction. I recognize 011, or 3, as the source register and 101, or 5, as the destination register. I know that the 1 signifies immediate mode or the second operand is directly in the instruction.

From here, I know that the second operand is 11111 or -1 in decimal and that it will be sign extended (SEXT) before being added to the data in the source register.

Does anyone know what the logical component I highlighted does?

The component is shaped like an isosceles trapezoid, and has three inputs: seemingly, two data inputs and one control input.

Comment: Related question: [What is happening in this part of the LC3?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/41727/528)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at slide 5-43 "Data Path Revisited" these are `MUX`, [multiplexors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer).

As such they are a "switch": When the red input is `1`, we have immediate mode and the `SEXT` output is passed through unchanged. When it is `0` it needs to look up a value based on the `SEXT` value and some memory or register.

Also in the slides, a `MUX` is represented again at `BR` and `JMP`, slides 5-31 and 5-35, again without actually clearly defining the alternative scenarios, and the `BR` case confuses the issue a bit because it clearly calculates a relative jump previously.

I'd guess the red input is the result of the branch condition and if false the original `PC` is passed through, but if that was the case they might as well have connected up the lines in this diagram.

For the `JMP` it is currently showing an absolute jump and under a different red arrow input it could be an indirect jump, similar to the `ADD` case.

(My latter suggestions have not actually been reconsidered much after reviewing slide 5-43.)